# In Bootstrap, how would you change background color of dropdown menu header whose parent is transparent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched the whole Internet, but none of the solutions work.

**What I am trying to do?**

I want to change the background color of the dropdown menu header.

https://ibb.co/cthhTk

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Blackbird </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"> Search </a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Sign In/Up <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dropdownMenu">
                        <li><a href="#"> Sign Up </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Sign In </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="seperator"><a href="#" class="not-active"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Article </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Neither does this work: */

.dropdown {

    background-color: #E32636;
}

/* Nor this: */

/* .navbar .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li > a {

       background-color: #E32636;
   }
*/
```

Comment: This will: `.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu  li > a`. See no space between `.navbar` and `.navbar-default`. If it still don't work, add `!important` tag to color property.

Comment: I want to change background color of dropdown menu header not the dropdown menu as you can see in the picture i want to change the silver color of dropdown header to some other color

Comment: I just pointed your problem. What is **header** for you in dropdown menu?

Comment: "Sign In/Up" when clicked its color is silver i want to change it to some other color see picture that i have provided in the question you would get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">              
    <div class="container">                 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
                </button>                                                       
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Blackbird </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"> Search </a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" id="authentication" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Sign In/Up <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dropdownMenu">
                            <li><a href="#"> Sign Up </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Sign In </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                           
                </ul>                   
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="seperator"><a href="#" class="not-active"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Article </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
    </div>      
</nav>
```

I have added an ID to the hyperlink which opens the signIn/signOut menu.

and then add a background color to it, so

```
#authentication{
  background-color: #f60;
}
```

or, if you really dont wanna add a new ID or a class, you can query the element as something like,

```
navbar navbar-collapse>ul>li:nth-child(2)>a{
  background-color: #f60;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this working code:

```css
.navbar-nav > li.dropdown.open a, .navbar-nav > li.dropdown.open a:focus, .navbar-nav > li.dropdown.open a:hover{
    background-color: #E32636;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu { 
    background-color: #E32636;              
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">              
    <div class="container">                 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
                </button>                                                       
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Blackbird </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"> Search </a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Sign In/Up <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" class="dropdownMenu">
                            <li><a href="#"> Sign Up </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Sign In </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                           
                </ul>                   
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="seperator"><a href="#" class="not-active"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Article </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
    </div>      
</nav>
```

You can also check this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfzLrdsk/1/)